# servlet cookie problem

Tags: java, servlets

i am trying to read values from a cookie like this

```
uid = cookie_user.getValue();
```

but then it throws the error that variable cookie_user might not have been initialized ... while i checked in firefox that the cookie is set up and also contains the required value ... what am i doing wrong and how do i fix this

Comment: Please, give us more code. Especially before line `uid = cookie_user.getValue();`

Answer (score 1):

I think that "variable cookie_user might not have been initialized" is a Java compilation error.  It is telling you that there are *possible* paths in your code in which it will reach that statement without setting `cookie_user`.

If you provided the code of the method containing that line, it would be possible to be more specific about the problem.

---

I doubt that this has anything to do with an actual cookie being set in your web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Are u doin like this

`Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
  for(int i=0; i<cookies.length; i++) 
  {
     Cookie cookie_user = cookies[i];
     System.out.println(cookie_user.getValue());
  }`

Comment: i used substituion on the for loop inside an if statement to solve the problem